# Maven profiles being ignored in Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My project has some .JARs that are defined in profiles. For instance, load the PostgreSQL JAR if the PostgreSQL profile is active, or load the MySQL JAR if the MySQL profile is active.

I have this project imported to IDEA, and set the PostgreSQL profile active in the Maven Panel, yet the jar is not added when the artifact is built, so it's not deployed to Tomcat, and then the WebApp doesn't start.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please [submit a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with a sample project to reproduce. Also attach `idea.log` (Help | Reveal Log in ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's an [acknowledged bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97932) in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
Some projects had the 
`<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` option in some of the profiles and they would not build (cos I have more that one maven modules in my project).

I removed that option and activeted each profile for each project alone. I worked but the behaviour is not the same with that of IntelliJ 11 or 10.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've found a more important maven bug in IntelliJ which I submitted to their tracker. Once that one is fixed I'll be able to check this one again.